# What does 'whose' mean in this sentence?

Tags: whose

> Nimzowitsch did not write a simple handbook of opening lines, but a manual of chess. The opinions, ideas, and generalisations that he describes gave rise to a true revolution, whose consequences we can correctly evaluate today.

I can't understand what 'whose' mean in this sentence. Is it Nimzowitsch's consequences? or the consequences of the opinions, ideas, and generalisations?

Comment: I agree that the sentence was somewhat ambiguous about which consequences were meant. It didn't help that the previous sentence included a "who": Nimzowitsch. I would have preferred "the consequences of which" rather than "whose consequences," but as SP999 implies, restating the word "revolution" would be better than using a pronoun with too many possible antecedents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "We can correctly evaluate the consequences of the **revolution**."

Some examples from [WHOSE | meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whose)

> used for adding information about a person or thing just mentioned:
>
> Cohen, whose short film won awards, was chosen to direct the movie.
>
> There was a picture in the paper of a man whose leg had been blown
>   off.
>
> They meet in an old house, whose basement has been converted into a
>   chapel.
>
> Fraud detectives are investigating the company, three of whose senior
>   executives have already been arrested.